# How to serialize a HashMap with BufferedOutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedoutputstream

I have a very large HashMap of the format `HashMap<String, List<String>>`, and I want to serialize it using `BufferedOutputStream` because I think that it will be more efficient than with a regular `OutputStream`.

But how do I divide the HashMap in chunks of the size of the buffer? Should I just iterate through the HashMap?

Comment: Where are you serializing the object into: SSD, RAM, S3? You might not get any performance benefit with `BufferedOutputStream` if it's RAM.

Comment: A file in a HDD. It's a file that may be read multiple times. Does that mean I should approach it differently?

Comment: You don't need to divide the hashmap in chunks. Just wrap your buffered stream into an ObjectOutputStream, and use writeObject() to write your HashMap. The BufferedStream will make sure all by itself to bufferize the multiple writes that writeObject() might do, and to write to the underlying stream when its internal buffer is full.

Comment: Thanks, @JBNizet . Do you mean something like this? FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);BufferedOutputStream bout = ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fout));?

Comment: That wouldn't compile. An ObjectOutputStream is not a BufferedOutputStream. You first wrap the OutputStream into a BufferedOutputStream. And you then wrap the BuffuredOutputStream into an ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to write into a local file you need to chain `FileOutputStream`, `BufferedOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. With below setup `BufferedOutputStream` should minimize direct writes to the file system using default buffer of 8192 bytes.

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("myKey", List.of("A", "B", "C"));

File outFile = new File("out.bin");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
     BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
    oos.writeObject(data);
    oos.flush();
}
```

Unless the output file is too big there is no need for further chunking.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what is more efficient if I don't want to store the information about the class and just the String and List<String> so that I can quickly read through the file and find exactly the key?

Comment: Instead of using Java serialization which is very verbose use Protobuf/Thrift format or write your own format. Finding quickly by key in a file is generally not possible unless you have ordered the entries somehow e.g. read how database builds an index for a column.

Comment: My idea was to have a hashmap <String, Integer> where the String is the key and the Integer is the number of bytes/characters from the beginning of the file until the beginning of the values of that key (basically, the position in the file). Do you think that could work?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki
Could you please show chunking example in your answer if the output file is too large?
Thanks